# Wordpress blog site just shows "welcome to nginx" after my vps was halted by support

Tags: debian, nginx, vps, wordpress

My vps was recently halted due to coin mining. I worked that out with support and the vps is back but now my wordpress site is not working. It's just showing "Welcome to nginx" instead of the wordpress site. It was working fine before they halted the system.

Comment: Sounds like they wiped your server and you need to reinstall wordpress and your data.

Comment: Its all still there. wp-admin still works. I just the get welcome to nginx page instead of my site when I go to the main url.

Comment: So this is your VPS, so you installed nginx and wordpress?  So have you checked the nginx document root to see if it is still pointing at your wordpress install?  What else have you checked?

Comment: I figured it out. The nginx conf was pointed at my wordpress install but there was an index.html which contained the "welcome to nginx" AND an index.php which was the wordpress index. I guess nginx defaults to index.html when both files exist? Anyways, I moved the index.html file to index.html_bak and the wordpress site loads correctly now. I really didn't know where to start so thank you for just getting me started looking somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the issue. See Paul's comment above. Here is my comment reply with what I did to fix the issue:

> I figured it out. The nginx conf was pointed at my wordpress install but there was an index.html which contained the "welcome to nginx" AND an index.php which was the wordpress index. I guess nginx defaults to index.html when both files exist? Anyways, I moved the index.html file to index.html_bak and the wordpress site loads correctly now. I really didn't know where to start so thank you for just getting me started looking somewhere